# eclipse api's to get current project's repository url

Tags: eclipse, plugins

i am working on developing a eclipse plugin which takes code from repository and builds the code in hudson.
for that i need to get the repository url of pom.xml
are there any eclipse api's to get repository url of current project.

for example i have got the workspace of current project using this api.

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath;


IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IPath location = root.getLocation();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to "[stand on the shoulders of giants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants)". Eclipse has now integrated m2e from Sonatype  (formally m2eclipse), and I found the following in an [XML file](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/plan.xml)

> M2E provides both a framework for building Maven-centric Eclipse
>         tools and set of tools and user interface elements directly
>         consumable by Eclipse Users.
>   As a framework, M2E provides facilities to import and configure
>           Maven projects in Eclipse workspace as well as APIs that allow
>           m2e extensions to access Maven project metadata and participate in
>           Maven project configuration and workspace build.

So you should look into [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) and check if the API allows what you want to do. I would start with plugin `org.eclipse.m2e.core` and study how to get access to the maven project ...

Answer (score 0):

I think eclipse may not know the repository url in pom.xml,the eclipse maven plugin can tell you about them,but why not manually analyze the pom.xml as resource file?

Comment: i don't want the repository url inside pom.xml,basically i want the repository url where the pom.xml is,so that i can take the pom file for there to build in hudson.does eclipse maven plugin do the same.

Comment: That depends on the configuration. If the POM contains that information, it will work. However, the information could be in the settings of the user or even Maven installation.